# Using repetition code (3,1) on H.264/AVC NAL header and encapsulating using RTP

Tags: c++, directshow, h.264, rtsp, rtp

I'm trying implementing simple repetition code (3,1) on H.264/AVC stream and broadcasting it
using RTP. But something goes wrong...

What I did is to take the AVC stream something like this in HEX :

00 00 00 01 67 48 D4 78 ....

and use repetition code (3,1):

00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 01 67 67 67 48 48 48 D4 D4 D4 78 78 78 ....

As you can see I did RC(3,1) per BYTE, when I encapsulate using RTP and broadcast it
on the receiver side after the packet has been decupsulated by RTSP receiver the received byte
sequence is no the same (The loss is 0%).
First i receive only half the data transmitted, and i get distortions at 00 00 00 01
(Start Code prefix) and at the blocks adjacent to the start code perfix.

Comment: I wonder what is the whole point of putting a broken H.264 bitstream into RTP? Obviously, RTSP client would not be able to come up with anything making sense out of this damaged data.

Comment: Okay whats what i'm wondering where I can damage the data and where i can't, RFC is not so clear about that.

Comment: Imagine what you receive on depacketizer side? RTP messages where you cannot actually rebuild original NAL units from.

Comment: Weel I did build the original NALS, though I didn't duplicate the start code prefix this time.